# How to convert list (with multi elements) into string without turn to "c("xxx","xxx","xxx")" R

Tags: r, list, sorting, split, data.table

```
library(data.table)

# Target string to convert

DATE_DATA <- c("2015-01-02;2015-01-07;2021-05-02;2019-02-05",
"2017-08-02;2000-01-22;2003-03-07;2017-10-09",
"2013-08-02;2022-06-02;2012-03-15")

# Dataset
DT <- data.table(NAME = c("JOE","MARY","PAUL"),DATE = c(DATE_DATA))
```

Expected result -- convert DATE column in a new column call "period" like below:
**split + sorted decreasing = F + unique year**

```
#  period
1: 2015,2019,2021
2: 2000,2003,2017
3: 2012,2013,2022
```

The approaches like below i have don't meet excepted result

```
# 1st approach -- RESULT : created column with class -- "list"

DT[,period:= lapply(strsplit(DT$DATE,";"),
                                 function(x) sort(unique(str_sub(x,1,4)),
                                                  decreasing = FALSE))]

# 2nd approach -- RESULT : created column with class -- "character" but value
#                          turn to "c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx")" , not expected 
#                          "xxx,xxx,xxx"

DT[,period:= as.character(paste(lapply(strsplit(DT$DATE,";"),
                             function(x) sort(unique(str_sub(x,1,4)),
                                              decreasing = FALSE)),collapse = ","))]
```

What step did i missed ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each `DATE` we can split the `DATE` column on ";", convert them into Date, extract the year using `format`, take the unique years and paste them together using `toString`.

```
DT$Period <- sapply(DT$DATE, function(x) 
         toString(sort(unique(format(as.Date(strsplit(x, ";")[[1]]), "%Y")))))
DT

#   NAME                                        DATE           Period
#1:  JOE 2015-01-02;2015-01-07;2021-05-02;2019-02-05 2015, 2019, 2021
#2: MARY 2017-08-02;2000-01-22;2003-03-07;2017-10-09 2000, 2003, 2017
#3: PAUL            2013-08-02;2022-06-02;2012-03-15 2012, 2013, 2022
```

---

We can reduce the `as.Date` and `format` step using the year function from the `lubridate` package which gives the same output.

```
library(lubridate)
DT$Period <- sapply(DT$DATE, function(x) 
                   toString(sort(unique(year(strsplit(x, ";")[[1]])))))
```

---

I am not a `data.table` expert but I think the thing which you are missing from your attempt is the grouping (`by`) parameter because currently it is giving you unique year from the entire `DATE` column, you need to specify that you need `unique` year for each row separately which is mentioned in the `by` argument.

```
DT[,period:= paste(sapply(strsplit(DATE,";"),
  function(x) sort(unique(substr(x,1,4)),)),collapse = ","), by = 1:nrow(DT)]

DT

#   NAME                                        DATE         period
#1:  JOE 2015-01-02;2015-01-07;2021-05-02;2019-02-05 2015,2019,2021
#2: MARY 2017-08-02;2000-01-22;2003-03-07;2017-10-09 2000,2003,2017
#3: PAUL            2013-08-02;2022-06-02;2012-03-15 2012,2013,2022
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using `gsub` and `scan`

```
DT[,  Period := toString(sort(unique(scan(text=gsub("-\\d+", 
               "", DATE), what = numeric(), sep=";")))), NAME]
DT
#   NAME                                        DATE           Period
#1:  JOE 2015-01-02;2015-01-07;2021-05-02;2019-02-05 2015, 2019, 2021
#2: MARY 2017-08-02;2000-01-22;2003-03-07;2017-10-09 2000, 2003, 2017
#3: PAUL            2013-08-02;2022-06-02;2012-03-15 2012, 2013, 2022
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`, where we reshape into 'long' format by splitting the 'DATE' at `;`, grouped by 'NAME', `summarise` the 'Period' as the `sort`ed `year` of the converted `Date` class (`ymd`), do a join with the original dataset and `select` the columns to the appropriate order (if needed)

```
library(tidyverse)
DT %>% 
   separate_rows(DATE, sep = ";") %>% 
   group_by(NAME) %>% 
   summarise(Period = toString(sort(unique(year(ymd(DATE)))))) %>% 
   right_join(DT) %>%
   select(names(DT), everything())
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  NAME  DATE                                        Period                
#  <chr> <chr>                                       <chr>                 
#1 JOE   2015-01-02;2015-01-07;2021-05-02;2019-02-05 2015, 2019, 2021
#2 MARY  2017-08-02;2000-01-22;2003-03-07;2017-10-09 2000, 2003, 2017
#3 PAUL  2013-08-02;2022-06-02;2012-03-15            2012, 2013, 2022
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the fastest way to do this, but one relatively easy to read and understand would be:

```
DT[, period:=sapply(strsplit(DATE, ";"), 
     function(x) paste(sort(unique(year(as.Date(x)))), collapse = ","))]
```

With the resulting output being:

```
   NAME                                        DATE         period
1:  JOE 2015-01-02;2015-01-07;2021-05-02;2019-02-05 2015,2019,2021
2: MARY 2017-08-02;2000-01-22;2003-03-07;2017-10-09 2000,2003,2017
3: PAUL            2013-08-02;2022-06-02;2012-03-15 2012,2013,2022
```

The `strsplit(DATE, ";")` would give you a column of type list. This means you can apply lapply function to this column, which will take each row and apply some function to it. Then it is just a matter of how to convert a character vector of your dates to the sorted years